# How to save Gravity form data for non-logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have created a **multi-step gravity form**.

Here , any users ( Logged In / Non-Logged In ) can see this form.

Talking about **Non-Logged In users** , if the user visits the form and fill the form by completinging ALL 6 steps , and when at the end , User submit Form , One **Login POP-UP** will be shown.( As shown in screen-shot) It will redirect the user to the login page.

[image]

[image]

**My requirement is** : After successful login , the user will be redirect to same Gravity form page , and on Last (6th step ) , with all details pre-filled.

How do I generate **"Save and Continue Later" LINK** for **Non-Logged In users** and when user clicks on **"SUBMIT"** button

EDIT :

Gravity form also have this **"Save and Continue Later"** functionality ( As shown in the screen-shot ) , which generate LINK like this **https://site_url/page-name/?gf_token=some_token** , and we can use this link to **RESUME form** .

[image]

But that link redirects to the page shown in the below screens-shot

[image]

**But I want to generate this LINK , on SUBMIT FORM click button and YET redirect to LOGIN PAGE**

Comment: Check this : https://gravitywiz.com/automatic-save-and-continue-with-gravity-forms/
may be it will help you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery way here!

For Non-Logged In users :

1. Hide the form SUBMIT button.
2. Then, SHOW "Save and Continue Later" link , for only LAST PAGE of your multi-step form.
3. Add CSS "Save and Continue Later" link , same as SUBMIT button.
4. On click of "Save and Continue Later" link , hide the content , that you have showed in the last screen-shot.
5. Save that generated link in the COOKIE , and use that COOKIE for redirection after Login.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not do this for non-Logged In users for this form.

But you can use [Gravity Perks, Forms Repeater Addon](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/) to make Nested Forms which may work because it is not saved in the same way in the cookie.